# When first testng program running at IntellJi IDE getting a error

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

This is the first Testng program,

```
public class FirstTestCase
{
    @Test
    void setup()
    {
        System.out.println("Setup - Open Browser and Application");
    }
    @Test
    void Login()
    {
        System.out.println("Login to the Application");
    }
    @Test
    void Close()
    {
        System.out.println("Close to the Application");
    }
}
```

```
**Test Framework quit unexpectedly**

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin\java.exe" -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=57678:C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 @C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_arg_file1851917645 com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter -usedefaultlisteners false -socket57677 @w@C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_working_dirs_testng.tmp -temp C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_testng.tmp
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:101)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1**
```

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin\java.exe" -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=61707:C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2\plugins\testng\lib\testng-rt.jar;C:\Users\dell\IdeaProjects\FTC\out\production\FTC;F:\Drivers\testng-7.7.1.jar;F:\Drivers\jcommander-1.7.jar" com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter -usedefaultlisteners false -socket61706 @w@C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_working_dirs_testng.tmp -temp C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_testng.tmp
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at org.testng.log4testng.Logger.lambda$getLogger$0(Logger.java:30)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
at org.testng.log4testng.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:30)
at org.testng.TestNG.(TestNG.java:110)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:101)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 5 more

Process finished with exit code 1**